How to make Spring to use HTTPS for redirects
I'm having a service that is behind a gateway. For the sub service all request are http. For redirects that are in the location header attribute the scheme of the url has to be https (otherwise the browser does not like it)
I'm using ModelAndView to do a redirect like below
return new ModelAndView("redirect:confirm")

In that case the scheme of the url in the location header is http.
I tried the following setting but it didn't work (it causes redirect loops in the browser)
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
    ....
        .requiresChannel(channelRequestMatcherRegistry -> channelRequestMatcherRegistry.requestMatchers("/confirm").requiresSecure())
        .build();
  }

What is the best way to force spring to use https for certain redirect url insted of http?
I'm using spring boot 3.2.x and spring web security 6.2.x

Cant answer your question, but I do not recommend http requests, as the http response is also transmitted insecurely and could be manipulated in any ways (e.g., change the Location header).

the request are https. only from the gateway to the service itself are http. I'm not 100% sure but i guess that's the reason why spring is also using http for the redirect .

Correct afaik. As spring does not know what the browser is using httpS to your gateway, and the gateway does TLS offloading to your service. Spring thinks it is reached via http. Check if you can forward the protocol schema via X- http header.
